# Can I directly pass the FitBit callback URL to the redux store but not the React views?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, fitbit

I have just started working on React/Redux and currenlty I'm trying to get data from FitBit API and use it in my react-redux app. I have put my callback url in Fitbit as http://localhost:9000/callback.

Currently I'm handling the callback URL at the view layer in React. And given below is my code.

This is part where I have done React routing. The callback URL is handled from the /callback route.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

import Auth from './components/Auth';
import Home from './components/Home';
import NotValid from './components/NotValid';
import CallBack from './components/CallBack';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                <Route path='/app' component={Auth}/>
                <Route path='/callback' component={CallBack}/>
                <Route component={NotValid}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is React view layer I'm handling the callback URL.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CallBack extends Component {


    render() {

        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        var parts = hash.split("=");
        var temp_two = parts[1].split("&");
        var access_token = temp_two[0];

        console.log("Access token is > " + access_token);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Authorization with Fitbit was made!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CallBack;
```

`window.location.hash.substr(1)` is used to capture the URL.

I'm wondering whether is there a way to directly handle the Fitbit callback URL in the redux store or at least not in the view layer.

Comment: I'll try to stop back and answer this if someone else doesn't in a bit. But quick answer, you're right. Your callback component isn't the right way to use React for this. React without Redux, you can use state. With Redux, a store is a valid option. But, if you aren't building a large app with a TON of routes, I don't Redux is necessary unless there is going to be a lot of other state management. Import to solve the right problems at the time or if you know you're bigger picture is an complex state application.

Comment: @DanDiGangi I'm just trying to get an idea how these things work together in a proper application. I'm a beginner to react - redux applicationss.